# Static files not loading in django app + nginx server + docker

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

I have a django app I want to host on virtual machine via a docker container and I am using an nginx server to run the application. The problem now is i am not sure how to configure the nginx server to ensure that static files are being served. This is how the admin page loads without static files
[image]

Here are my configuration files

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir -p /kings

WORKDIR  /kings

COPY requirements.txt /kings/requirements.txt

COPY ./kings /kings

RUN pip install -r /kings/requirements.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /kings/entrypoint.sh
CMD ["sh", "/kings/entrypoint.sh"]
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  kings-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./DockerFile
    volumes:
      - .:/kings
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    image: kings-app:kings
    container_name:kings-ap
    depends_on:
      - kings-redis
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=${ALLOWED_HOSTS}
      - REDIS_HOST=${REDIS_HOST}
      - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
  kings-redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: kings-redis
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: kings-nginx
    ports:
      - "1337:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./static:/kings/static
    depends_on:
      - kings-app
```

#### nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;

    upstream app_server {
        server kings-app:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /static/ {
            alias /kings/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

#### entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py migrate --no-input
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input


gunicorn kings.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

#### static files settings

[image]

These files are all in the root folder of the project

Comment: Share your static related configurations from settings.py.

Comment: @Marco I have added that to the question

Comment: How does your URL's look like in the frontend? I guess they can't be resolved. What can you see in the nginx logs? Btw. try `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")` to set your STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: @marco That did not help. The admin page still loads without the static files

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to remove slash after "static" in your nginx.conf location /static**/** {
alias /kings/static/;
}

In real it should look like that:

```
location /static {
            alias /kings/static/;
        }
```

The next thing you should try to modify your settings.py:
in the beginning of your settings.py you should add: `import os`
and modify you static root

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

Try to check that there is no error 403 on your web-page. It means that you have permission issues.

And try to run `python manage.py collectstatic` in your environment